# How to know or catch exception when using nextResult() if a connection is broken using Java Smack API?

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I'm developing an application using Java Smack API. I use the PacketCollector.java class' nextResult() method to receive the next incoming message. (According the doc, this method blocks until there is input.)

http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/PacketCollector.html

I have a question concerning what if the connection is abruptly broken (say, by network disconnection and so on), how do I know or how can I catch the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nextResult()` call will wait until a packet that matches the filter arrives. Looking at the source I think it would even wait after a disconnect and reconnect, as long as you use the same connection instance.

You shouldn't really use `nextResult()`, use `nextResult(long)` instead. `nextResult()` does not throw an exception if the connection is disconnected for whatever reason and there is no good reason to use `nextResult()` instead of `nextResult(long)` with an reasonable timeout value.